# Перенос строки через определенное кол-во символов при наличии пробела JS

Tags: javascript

Помогите, есть допустим фраза (как пример): "Если тебе тяжело, значит ты поднимаешься в гору. Если тебе легко, значит ты летишь в пропасть."

Нужно чтобы если есть пробел в районе 20 символов реагировало на самый дальний и переносило строку вниз. (Если тебе тяжело, зн) Вот 20 символов должно среагировать на пробел после запятой и получиться вот так: Если тебе тяжело,(перенос строки)
значит ты(перенос строки)
поднимаешься в гору. (Ну и т.д)

Comment: Запоминайте позицию последнего пробела при обходе символов строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Алгоритм такой:  
    режем строку на массив слов
    кладём первое слово в текущую строку
    в цикле по массиву слов:
        если следующее слово не укладывается в лимит:
            текущая строка отправляется на выход
        или если текущая строка сама больше лимита: # такое может быть при наличии очень длинных слов)
            текущая строка отправляется на выход
        иначе:
            добавляем слово через пробел к текущей строке
    остатки в текущей строке отправляются на выход
```

```js
function splitN(str, N) {
  const words = str.trim().split(/\s+/g);
  const res = [];
  let cur_str = words.shift();
  for (const word of words) {
    if (cur_str.length + 1 + word.length >=N || cur_str.length>=N) {
      res.push(cur_str);
      cur_str = word;
    } else {
      cur_str += ' ' + word;
    }
  }
  res.push(cur_str);
  
  return res.join('\n');
}


const str = 'Если тебе тяжело, значит ты поднимаешься в гору. Если тебе легко, значит ты летишь в пропасть.';

console.log(splitN(str, 20));
```

> ```
> Если тебе тяжело,
> значит ты
> поднимаешься в
> гору. Если тебе
> легко, значит ты
> летишь в пропасть.
> ```